# How to use conditions on a REPLACE expression?

Tags: database

For an autocomplete, I'm searching a table of address (full address in one column).

Example: `123 Example building, Somestreet, Town, QW1E 2RT`

To improve the search I want to remove the space, so you can search `QW1E2RT` or `QW1E 2RT`, however, I obviously don't want that to be displayed to the user.

I think I'm most of the way there:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('mctable', 'mc');
$query->addField('mc', 'a_address');
$query->where('REPLACE(mc.a_address, \' \', \'\') LIKE \':value\'', [':value' => '%' . $string . '%']);
$query->distinct();
$rows = $query->execute();
```

The problem is that the `:value` placeholder doesn't appear to be passed through… If I hardcode a value in the "snippet" it works.

I originally tried with:

```
$query->addExpression('REPLACE(mc.a_address, \' \', \'\')', 'a_address');
$query->condition('a_address','%' . $query->escapeLike($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
```

But couldn't figure out how to use the expression in the condition.

Many Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code above is the apostrophes around the placeholder.

`LIKE \':value\'',` should be `LIKE :value',`.

I would still like to know how to do this with `addExpression` though :-/